# Jquery load is not loading page div from a page

Tags: jquery, load

I have tried this code.
If I try to load the full page, it works; but if I need a particular div from the page, it doesn't load at all.

This is my code:

```
$("li#blogs").on("click", "a#pagination-comments-blogs", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var url = $(this).attr("href");
  $("div#blogs-comments-display").slideUp();
  $("div#blogs-comments-display").load(url "div#blogs-comments-display").slideDown(1000);
});
```

If I put a comma between **url** and **"div#blogs-comments-display"**, as this:

`load(url, "div#blogs-comments-display").slideDown(1000);`

it loads the whole page, not the div.

Comment: Not sure this part is valid `.load(url "div#blogs-comments-display")`. Did you check your console for errors

Comment: What happens if you change it to `$("div#blogs-comments-display").load(url, "div#blogs-comments-display")`  (with a comma where the syntax error is)?

Comment: Unrelated(?):  Note the `slideUp()` `slideDown()` and `load()` return immediately - so your comments will never slide up/down as the down immediately cancels out the up and occurs before the load has completed.   Review the documentation for these and use the *callbacks* to start the next step.

Comment: @Carsten Løvbo Andersen, yes it shows url page is not found.

Comment: @ freedomn-m
if we put comma there whole page loads.. not the div content of that page

Comment: @freeman-m, sir if only this part is there $("div#blogs-comments-display").load(url).slideDown(1000); it works

Comment: My bad, it should be `.load(url + " " + "div#blogs-comments-display")`.  Your code, as provided, will give a syntax error: `SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list`  as `variable "string"` is not valid syntax, so **none of your code will be running** (due to the syntax error).   The browser console will be telling you this, along with any decent IDE, including [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/a62nbx45/).